# como hacer una subconsulta en laravel?

Tags: laravel, sql, subconsultas

quisiera saber como hacer una subconsulta segun esta consulta que tengo.

```
$f1 =new \Carbon\Carbon('28-01-2018 00:00:00');
    $f2 =new \Carbon\Carbon('28-01-2018 00:01:00');        

    $mov_enc =Mov_encabezado::join('mov_detalle','mov_encabezado.consecutivo','mov_detalle.consecutivo')

    ->join('registro','mov_encabezado.registro','registro.registro')
    ->join('paciente','paciente.historia','registro.historia')        
    ->join('servicio','mov_detalle.articulo','servicio.servicio')
    ->join('formula_encabezado','mov_encabezado.numero_orden','formula_encabezado.formula')
    ->join('unidad_servicio','mov_encabezado.unidad_servicio','unidad_servicio.unidad_servicio')
    ->join('progreso','progreso.registro','registro.registro')


    ->select('progreso.habitacion','paciente.nombre as paciente_nom','paciente.nombre2 as paciente_nom2','paciente.primer_apellido as paciente_primer_ap','paciente.segundo_apellido as paciente_segundo_ap','unidad_servicio.nombre as uniservicio','registro.registro','mov_detalle.articulo','mov_detalle.cantidad','servicio.descripcion','mov_encabezado.numero_orden')

    ->whereColumn('progreso.fecha','=','formula_encabezado.fecha_progreso')
    ->whereColumn('mov_detalle.articulo','=','servicio.servicio')

    ->whereColumn('registro.registro','=','progreso.registro')
    ->whereColumn('registro.historia','=','paciente.historia')
    ->whereColumn('mov_encabezado.registro','=','registro.registro')
    ->whereColumn('mov_encabezado.tipo_transaccion','=','mov_detalle.tipo_transaccion')
    ->whereColumn('mov_encabezado.consecutivo','=','mov_detalle.consecutivo')
    ->whereColumn('mov_encabezado.bodega','=','mov_detalle.bodega')
    ->whereColumn('mov_encabezado.numero_orden','=','formula_encabezado.formula')
    ->where('mov_encabezado.tipo_transaccion','=','VE')
    ->where('mov_encabezado.bodega','=','FA')

    ->whereBetween('mov_encabezado.fecha',[$f1 ,$f2 ])

    ->get();
```

quisiera agrupar los registro.registro,paciente.nombre y progreso.habitacion para que no se repita en la tabla. Es decir, que por cada habitacion y registro mostrar su atributos correspondientes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver en el ejemplo se repite los registro, cuando en realidad solo deberia parecer uno con sus demas atributos, espero me puedan colaborar.